# Debian preseed: How to force prompt for hostname and domain?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, pxe, netboot

I have a preseed file which works perfectly in that the install goes from start to finish fully automated without prompts.

However, I want to force a prompt for hostname and domain.

I have tried adding:

```
d-i netcfg/get_hostname seen false
d-i netcfg/get_domain seen false
```

However the installer just ignores this and I end up with a system with the default `debian` hostname etc.

`netcfg/get_hostname`, `d-i netcfg/dhcp_hostname` and `netcfg/get_domain` are **not** defined in my preseed file.

If it makes any difference, this question relates to Debian 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change isolinux/syslinux configuration and remove the `priority=critical` from the boot line. Or just change it to `priority=medium`.