# Debian net install to preseed hostname and domain name

Tags: debian, hostname, preseed

Basically the opposite of [Debian preseed: How to force prompt for hostname and domain?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563009/)

With the new Debian bullseye release, the net install is asking me for hostname and domain name. How to `preseed` it to disable such prompt?

- I used the same `preseed` file with the buster release, and cannot recall it asked for hostname and domain name or not. At least it was not causing me trouble.
- I check the [new Debian bullseye `preseed` sample file](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/example-preseed.txt) and found the setting is the same as mine.

```
# Any hostname and domain names assigned from dhcp take precedence over
# values set here. However, setting the values still prevents the questions
# from being shown, even if values come from dhcp.
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string my-hostname
d-i netcfg/get_domain string my-domain

# If you want to force a hostname, regardless of what either the DHCP
# server returns or what the reverse DNS entry for the IP is, uncomment
# and adjust the following line.
d-i netcfg/hostname string my-domain

# The wacky dhcp hostname that some ISPs use as a password of sorts.
d-i netcfg/dhcp_hostname string my-domain
```

How to preseed hostname and domain name to disable their prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I use the very same preseed, but what happens to me is that I have no prompts but hostname is settled to 'debian' that is not what I would like.

Comment: Oh, that's at least a progress (to my situation), 

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).